# Unknown Memory leak in android

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks

adb shell dumpsys meminfo of my package shows the following and my native allocated size increases and finally causing mobile restart. Is that any memory ? How can i fix that??

```
               native   dalvik    other    total    limit   bitmap nativeBmp
        size:   445456     5955      N/A   451411    32768      N/A      N/A

   allocated:   445024     3726      N/A   448750      N/A    10948     1912

        free:       43     2229      N/A     2272      N/A      N/A      N/A

       (Pss):   132631      870   300292   433793      N/A      N/A      N/A
```

(shared dirty):     2532     1656     5552     9740      N/A      N/A      N/A

```
(priv dirty):   132396      708   298960   432064      N/A      N/A      N/A
```

Objects
           Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
     AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
          Assets:        6    AssetManagers:        6
   Local Binders:        5    Proxy Binders:       14
Death Recipients:        1
 OpenSSL Sockets:        0

SQL
               heap:        0         MEMORY_USED:        0
 PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0         MALLOC_SIZE:       50

Asset Allocations
    zip:/data/app/com.outlook.screens-2.apk:/resources.arsc: 25K
    zip:/data/app/com.outlook.screens-2.apk:/assets/font/RobotoCondensedRegular.
ttf: 156K
    zip:/data/app/com.outlook.screens-2.apk:/assets/font/RobotoCondensedBold.ttf
: 158K
    zip:/data/app/com.outlook.screens-2.apk:/assets/font/RobotoCondensedLight.tt
f: 157K
Uptime: 190161845 Realtime now=432619753